# How would a minority share holder VETO power be provisioned in a company constitution?

Tags: contract-law, shareholders, limited-liability-company

To protect minority shareholder and potentially attract investors, a company would give minority shareholders the power to veto certain decisions. Typically decisions that would erode their shareholding value.

How would this be provisioned in the constitution while not giving them too much power to veto anything out?

For example, one can veto out any corporation restructuring, dilution of the
shareholdings, appointment of officers, election of directors, borrowing and lending and more.

Thanks

Comment: You have several tags. This is not likely to involve the constitution but would involve some form of corporate law. There is a big distinction between the way this might be answered for a corporation and an LLC.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It's an LLC. let me delete some tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### However you like; subject to the law

Your constitution can deal with any matters that take your fancy and can require whatever majority you like in order to make changes to some or all of it up to and including unanimity.